# Use Google search by Image uploading an image from gallery

Tags: android, google-image-search

I'm trying to create an Android application to recognize an image by Google images search. I want that a user provides an image to Google (by uploading it from the gallery) and Google returns the web page with the best guess for the loaded image.

I would open the google images search page (https://www.google.it/imghp?hl=it&tab=wi&ei=ZzCGWIW9EcyuswHu7KroDA&ved=0EKouCBYoAQ) inside of my activity.

But, in this page, in order to see the camera icon next to the search bar that lets you upload images, you must set your browser with the "pc view".
So how can I open in my activity this page directly in "view PC" mode? In addition there is a way to directly execute the image search using Google image search without opening the associated page but through an http request?
I am also interested in different approaches to the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To open the page in PC mode, you could set the user agent to that of a desktop browser

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("DESKTOP_USERAGENT");
```

An alternative would be to send the image to Chrome and allow the user to perform the reverse image search using the built-in menu, but that is no longer a native solution.